# How to get value with ajax with json?

Tags: php, json, ajax

Hello friend its my first question on stackoverflow i am facing problem in Json is not working with ajax. I am not able to understand and i didnt understood where problem. Myb code is following...
I have action.php file
If i am trying without json its working but i am using json is not get any response

```
<?php 
 $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "psycho"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA INSIDE */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
} 
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT qid, question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4 FROM question ORDER BY qid LIMIT 1")){
$stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
$stmt->bind_result($qid, $question, $opt1, $opt2, $opt3, $opt4); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THESE VARIABLES */
$stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
$stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
?>
<h1 id="question"><?php echo $question; ?></h1>
<input type="hidden" id="qid" value="<?php echo $qid; ?>">
<input type="radio" name="a1" id="op1" value="<?php echo $opt1; ?>"><span id="op1text"><?php echo $opt1; ?></span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="a1" id="op2" value="<?php echo $opt2; ?>"><span id="op2text"><?php echo $opt2; ?></span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="a1" id="op3" value="<?php echo $opt3; ?>"><span id="op3text"><?php echo $opt3; ?></span><br/>
<input type="radio" name="a1" id="op4" value="<?php echo $opt4; ?>"><span id="op4text"><?php echo $opt4; ?></span><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next"> <!-- THIS SERVES AS THE SUBMIT AND NEXT BUTTON -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){ /* WHEN SUBMIT IS CLICKED */
  var qid = $("#qid").val(); /* GET THE question id */
  var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='a1']:checked");
  if (selected.length > 0) { /* CHECK THE SELECTED RADIO BUTTON */
    answer = selected.val();
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", /* THE METHOD WE WILL BE USING TO PASS THE DATA */
    url: "action.php", /* THIS IS WHERE THE DATA WILL GO */
    data: {"questionid" : qid, "answer" : answer}, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(result){ /* WHEN IT IS SUCCESSFUL */
      /* THIS WILL REPLACE THE DATA IN OUR QUESTION PAGE */
      $("#qid").val(result.questionid);
      $("#question").html(result.question);
      $("#op1").val(result.op1);
      $("#op2").val(result.op2);
      $("#op3").val(result.op3);
      $("#op4").val(result.op4);
      $("#op1text").html(result.op1);
      $("#op2text").html(result.op2);
      $("#op3text").html(result.op3);
      $("#op4text").html(result.op4);
    }
  }); /* END OF AJAX */
});
});
 </script>
```

My second file code is here
action.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["questionid"])){
/* INCLUDE OUR NEW ESTABLISHED CONNECTION HERE */
/* PUT HERE YOUR INSERT QUERY WHICH STORES THE USER'S ANSWERS */

/* THEN FETCH THE NEXT QUESTION */
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT qid, question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4 FROM question WHERE qid > ? ORDER BY qid LIMIT 1")){
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["questionid"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($qid, $question, $opt1, $opt2, $opt3, $opt4);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

/* THIS SET OF DATA WILL REPLACE THE DATA IN OUR CURRENT QUESTION PAGE */
echo json_encode(array("questionid" => $qid, "question" => $question, "op1" => $opt1, "op2" => $opt2, "op3" => $opt3, "op4", => op4));
   } /* END OF ISSET */
?>
```

Comment: Are your `<input>` elements within a `<form>` tag at all?

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console; what response is coming back for the AJAX POST request?

Comment: I suggest you also check out these posts... [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Answer (score 2):

You should include the following code to change the type of data in the header.

`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Once you add this to your PHP code JQuery will be able to read the JSON Respons, this is because without specifying this content type, PHP naturally responds with a content type of HTML unless specified elsewhere.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that without this header set, php is probably saying that the content type is HTML, so jquery thinks it’s html and not json, and so it’s not going to try to parse the json. (Just for a little further explanation of your answer.) A content type tells a browser (or any other client) what format the content is, because realistically it’s all just a big string of text, until you know how to parse it (is it json? is it html? is it javascript? is it xml? is it a picture? etc etc)

Comment: OP has `dataType: 'json'` so while this is generally good advice, it won't make a difference

Answer (score -1):

use this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit").click(function(){ /* WHEN SUBMIT IS CLICKED */
      var qid = $("#qid").val(); /* GET THE question id */
      var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='a1']:checked");
      if (selected.length > 0) { /* CHECK THE SELECTED RADIO BUTTON */
        answer = selected.val();
      }
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", /* THE METHOD WE WILL BE USING TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* THIS IS WHERE THE DATA WILL GO */
        data: {"questionid" : qid, "answer" : answer}, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){ /* WHEN IT IS SUCCESSFUL */
          /* THIS WILL REPLACE THE DATA IN OUR QUESTION PAGE */

           var result = JSON.parse(data);              

          $("#qid").val(result.questionid);
          $("#question").html(result.question);
          $("#op1").val(result.op1);
          $("#op2").val(result.op2);
          $("#op3").val(result.op3);
          $("#op4").val(result.op4);
          $("#op1text").html(result.op1);
          $("#op2text").html(result.op2);
          $("#op3text").html(result.op3);
          $("#op4text").html(result.op4);
        }
      }); /* END OF AJAX */
    });
    });
     </script>
```

Comment: What is different?

Comment: var result = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: This and OP's code both have `dataType: 'json'` so assuming a valid JSON string is returned, jQuery will automatically parse the result